# ERROR DURING WINRM SEND INPUT - attempting to recover: WinRMOperationTimeoutError

Tags: automation, ansible, devops, winrm

#### Error

I'm running some ansible playbook to configure windows server.

I encounter the error:

```
TASK [windows_roles : Install all security updates with automatic reboots] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 02 June 2023  08:56:04 +0000 (0:00:12.150)       0:00:12.255 *********** 
[WARNING]: ERROR DURING WINRM SEND INPUT - attempting to recover: WinRMOperationTimeoutError
```

#### Version

**Windows Version:** Windows Server 2019

**Runner:** Alpine:3.15

#### Playbook

```
- name: Install all security updates with automatic reboots
  ansible.windows.win_updates:
    category_names:
    - SecurityUpdates
    - CriticalUpdates
    reboot: yes

# Optionally, you can increase the reboot_timeout to survive long updates during reboot
- name: Ensure we wait long enough for the updates to be applied during reboot
  ansible.windows.win_updates:
    reboot: yes
    reboot_timeout: 3600
```

#### WinRM setup

```
ansible_connection: "winrm"
ansible_password: ((service-account-awx.password))
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_user: ((service-account-awx.username))
ansible_winrm_transport: "kerberos"
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: "true"
```

I don't really understand where this error could come from. I have other job running, with the same playbook, from the same runner, to other server hosted in the same network.

If you have any idea of what to test to troubleshoot...

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug related to Ansible.Windows collection. See https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.windows/issues/516